# Don't install npm dev dependencies via --omit=dev does not work

Tags: npm

I tried everything but nothing works. I still see dev dependencies in the `package-lock.json` file, but in `node_modules` they are gone from `.package-lock.json` file and the folders are empty (for example `@loki` folder).

Commands I tried:

```bash
npm install --omit=dev
npm prune --production
npm install --omit=dev --omit=optional
```

Running on npm 10 and Node 18.17.

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@prefixx/components12",
  "version": "2.3.18",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "module": "dist/components12.mjs",
  "main": "dist/components12.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "storybook dev -p 6007 --ci",
    "dev": "storybook dev -p 6007",
    "build:storybook": "cross-env STORYBOOK_BUILD=true storybook build -o ../../storybook-static/native",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lit": "^3.1.1",
    "lit-html": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.2.8",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "0.4.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "composed-offset-position": "^0.0.4",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.13",
    "loki": "^0.33.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "rollup-plugin-ignore": "^1.0.10",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

Some code from `package-lock.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@eliagroup-innersource/nova-components-native",
  "version": "2.3.18",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "@eliagroup-innersource/nova-components-native",
      "version": "2.3.18",
      "dependencies": {
        "lit": "^3.1.1",
        "lit-html": "^3.1.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@eliagroup-innersource/nova-core": "2.3.0",
        "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.2.8",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "0.5.3",
        "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "0.4.4",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "composed-offset-position": "^0.0.4",
        "flatpickr": "4.6.13",
        "loki": "^0.33.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "rollup-plugin-ignore": "^1.0.10",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.0"
      }
    },

....

 "node_modules/@loki/browser": {
      "version": "0.33.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@loki/browser/-/browser-0.33.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-PpgzttbfjLh2fkkObM1ljPd4guqwbMpuH+wefwef+qJBhwQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@loki/integration-core": "^0.33.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@loki/core": {
      "version": "0.33.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@loki/core/-/core-0.33.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-TbgKfAfxYxQffRIwSYelhkC2y4/wegwe==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
        "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
      }
    },

....
```

You can see loki for example, which has a vulnerability (`npm audit`) because of an old version of axios it uses, is still in `package-lock.json`, but it's a dev dependency I don't want in production.

Comment: What you're describing is what's _supposed_ to happen. They're not removed from the lockfile, they're still in the dependency tree (and we still need to remember which specific versions), they're just **not installed**. If you want to remove all the dev dependencies entirely, `npm uninstall` them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. Then the problem is that npm audit runs the audit also on the devdependencies in the lock file. When we deploy an npm package, other developers see this audit summary in the console it seems..